# How tokenize code with ANTLR v4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

at start i want to apologise for my bad english. 
I make webApp and my task what i need to do is to tokenize Java code. I found tool like ANTLR v4 and i tried to implements it.

```
public class Tokenizer {
  public void tokenizer(String code) {
    ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(code);
    Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(in);
    List<? extends Token> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();
    tokenList = lexer.getAllTokens();
    for(Token token : tokenList){
      System.out.println("Next token :" + token.getType() + "\n");
    }
  }
}
```

And this code print on screen list of int with number of token Type. 
I need something like this:

[image]

Code with something like "comments" to code. 
How can i get this result? 
I have this grammar : https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java8

Answer (score 1):

The `Token` class contains several methods including

```
int getLine();
int getCharPositionInLine();
```

that associate the token with the corresponding source.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
token.getText()
```

you should get the parsed text the token represents.

In addition, you should get the token's name by

```
lexer.getVocabulary().getSymbolicName(token.getType())
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You for answer.
code like here : 
'public void tokenizer(String code) {
   ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(code);
         Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(in);
         List<? extends Token> tokenList = new ArrayList<>();
         tokenList = lexer.getAllTokens();             
         
      
         for (Token token :  tokenList) {
          
          System.out.println(lexer.getVocabulary().getSymbolicName(token.getType()));
 }
 }
}'

Return me 
null
null
null
null...  
Method token.getText() return me string with element from Input Code ...

Comment: I copied your code into mine to run with the ANTLR4 Java8 grammar. The output gives me the following:
Identifier
Identifier
SEMI
INT
Identifier
SEMI
Identifier
ASSIGN
IntegerLiteral
SEMI
IF
LPAREN
Identifier
GT
IntegerLiteral
RPAREN
LBRACE
Identifier
ASSIGN
StringLiteral
SEMI
RBRACE
ELSE
LBRACE
Identifier
ASSIGN
StringLiteral
SEMI
RBRACE

Comment: If you want to extract more abstract knowlege as shown in your example, you have to parse the token stream and traverse the parse tree by a TreeWalker. The parser also has a vocabulary to query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing here is you want a mix of tokens and rules in the output. For instance `VARIABLE_DECLARATION` is actually a parser rule, while `IDENTIFIER ASSIGN IDENTIFIER` consists of 3 lexer rules. You can use the token stream to print the recognized lexems, but that won't give you any parser rule.

What you can try instead is to print the return parse tree, which you get when you do a real parse run on your input (see `ParseTree.toString()`). You can use a parser listener to walk a parse tree and transform that into a stream of rule descriptions along with the text that belongs to a rule (context).